# phpMyAdmin asking for login

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently i change my apache port to `8080` and the phpMyAdmin now asking for login, i'm trying to login with `root` and didnt work, its said that i need to login with a password, when i check on the `config.ini.php` on phpMyAdmin its say that `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;`, what should i do to make it works again?

[This is the phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgn69.png)

[This is the config.ini.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKseD.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your config.ini file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

It means your username is root and your password is also root.

Also if that didn't work out you can remove the root from the password line.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```